# Separar cada palavra da frase num índice da lista em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este trecho de código me gera a seguinte saída.

```
tamanho = len(lista_nome_base_docs)
print (tamanho)
lista_geral_de_lista_arquivos = []


for i in range(tamanho):
with open(lista_nome_base_docs[i],"r") as arquivo:
    conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
    lista_geral_de_lista_arquivos.append(conteudo)

print (lista_geral_de_lista_arquivos)
```

Saida:

```
[['Do mesmo modo, a consulta aos diversos militantes acarreta um processo de 
reformulacao e modernizacao do fluxo de informacoes.'], ['Evidentemente, a 
determinacao clara de objetivos promove a alavancagem dos niveis de 
motivacao departamental.'], ['Gostaria de enfatizar que a percepcao das 
dificuldades cumpre um papel essencial na formulacao das diretrizes de 
desenvolvimento para o futuro.']]
```

ou seja uma lista de listas.. porém na lista interna a frase está inteira dentro de uma posição da lista **['fraseinteira']** como que eu faço pra ela ficar desse jeito **['frase','inteira']**

Alguém saberia me dizer algum meio para fazer isto ou percorrer esta string dentro da posição da lista...

Comment: É a quarta pergunta que você abre relacionado a este assunto. Não seria mais fácil você descrever o que exatamente você precisa fazer e nós te ajudarmos no processo inteiro?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é porque estou realizando um trabalho.. e me aventurando com python....   e se for colocar o problema como um todo, acho que não seria um boa ideia, pois cada um estruturaria o problema de forma diferente, e o meu problema em si não é estruturar o problema e sim como  manipular algumas estruturas, por isso estou retirando dúvidas em partes.

Comment: Então basta utilizar o `split` para separar a frase em palavras.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então.. isso eu já sabia... o problema é como fazer isso pegando um lista de dentro de outra lista... por exemplo, estou rascunhando isso aqui:  `for numbers in lista_geral_de_lista_arquivos:
    for number in numbers:
        conteudo_string = lista_geral_de_lista_arquivos[number].split()
        lista_palavras.append(conteudo_string)`  porém ainda não deu certo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem uma lista de listas com apenas uma *string*. Semanticamente isso faz pouquíssimo, se não nada, de sentido, então possivelmente a maneira que está criando essas listas não seja a melhor forma. Mas se a intenção é possuir uma lista de lista das palavras de cada frase, para modificar a lista que possui atualmente, basta fazer:

```
lista = [
    ['Do mesmo modo, a consulta aos diversos militantes acarreta um processo de reformulacao e modernizacao do fluxo de informacoes.'], 
    ['Evidentemente, a determinacao clara de objetivos promove a alavancagem dos niveis de motivacao departamental.'], 
    ['Gostaria de enfatizar que a percepcao das dificuldades cumpre um papel essencial na formulacao das diretrizes de desenvolvimento para o futuro.']
]

for i, frase in enumerate(lista):
    lista[i] = frase[0].split()

print(lista)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/7ODQOV) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MOGV/0)</sup>

Assim, você terá uma lista de lista de palavras:

```
[
    ['Do', 'mesmo', 'modo,', 'a', 'consulta', 'aos', 'diversos', 'militantes', 'acarreta', 'um', 'processo', 'de', 'reformulacao', 'e', 'modernizacao', 'do', 'fluxo', 'de', 'informacoes.'], 
    ['Evidentemente,', 'a', 'determinacao', 'clara', 'de', 'objetivos', 'promove', 'a', 'alavancagem', 'dos', 'niveis', 'de', 'motivacao', 'departamental.'], 
    ['Gostaria', 'de', 'enfatizar', 'que', 'a', 'percepcao', 'das', 'dificuldades', 'cumpre', 'um', 'papel', 'essencial', 'na', 'formulacao', 'das', 'diretrizes', 'de', 'desenvolvimento', 'para', 'o', 'futuro.']
]
```

Comment: exatamente isso que estou aqui tentando fazer!

Answer (score 1):

De um modo muito elementar, seria isso:

```
>>> "Meu texto a ser separado em palavras".split()
['Meu', 'texto', 'a', 'ser', 'separado', 'em', 'palavras']
```

**Documentação:**
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 1):

Nesta questão basta passar a **frase** como parâmetro da lista. Para isso devemos implementar simplesmente o seguinte código abaixo...

```
frase_inteira = list(input('Digite a frase: ').split())
print(frase_inteira)
```

Observe que quando passamos uma string como parâmetro de uma lista, associada com a função *split()* a cadeia de string é dividida em substrings e cada uma dessas substrings são transformadas em elementos e armazenados na respectiva lista. Neste caso, quando pedimos para imprimir *frase_inteira*, nos é exibido uma lista na qual, cada elemento é uma substring da string principal, ou seja, substring da frase digitada.

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é utilizando `List Comprehension`. O código ficaria desta forma:

```
frase_inteira = [x for x in input('Digite a frase: ').split()]
print(frase_inteira)
```